# Finding theta of trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question, so I will give an example instead.
I know that $\cos(\theta)=0$ if $\theta$ is $\pm\frac\pi2$, or $\sin(\theta)=0$ if $\theta$ is $0$, $\pi$, etc. as those are clear from the graphs of $\cos$ and $\sin$.
However, if I had, for example, $\cos(\theta)=1/2$, how do I find $\theta$? (I know $\theta$ is $\pm \frac\pi3$ but how/why?)

Comment: Do you know the definition of cos and arccos?

Comment: adjacent/hypotenus

Comment: However, cos is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[-1, 1]$ and arccos is function from $[-1, 1]$ to $[0, \pi]$ and $arccos(cos(\theta)) = \theta$ for $\theta \in [0, \pi]$.

Comment: @TempJon What about $\arccos(x)$ (the arccosine, sometimes written as $\cos^{-1}(x)$)?

Comment: Take an equilateral triangle, and split it in half. Now find all of the trig ratios for $60^{\circ} = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$. It's easiest if you take the length of a side of the equilateral triangle to be $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the output of the function $\arccos x$ as the length (in radians) of the arc whose cosine is $x$ (I mean, that's the definition of $\arccos$). So
$$\cos\theta = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \theta = \arccos \frac{1}{2},$$
can be thought of the arc whose cosine is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I know about inverse trig, but how would I get an approximate pi over something value from that without a calculator?

Comment: I recommend you to look at [Taylor Series](http://people.duke.edu/~ad159/files/m128a/notes/3.pdf). You can find approximations with it. (That's how calculators do it).

Comment: You can find more information about Taylor Series expansion for **cosine** [here](http://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/the-maclaurin-expansion-of-cosx/)